# How to add an onClick function to a dynamically-filled div?

Tags: javascript, api

I have bootstrap navbar with dropdown:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">GANRES</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I have function that fills them with genres with the TMDb API:

```
async function getGenres() {
    let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=d80a54a0422d5fff6149c48741c8bece&language=en-US";
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let genres = await response.json();
    let navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item dropdown");
    navbar.innerHTML += `<div class="dropdown-menu">`;
    let nav = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
    for (let i = 0; i < genres.genres.length; i++) {
        nav[0].innerHTML += `<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">` + genres.genres[i].name + `</a>`;
    }

//This part should add separately to each element, but it does not work
//Here is error: Cannot set property 'click' of undefined at getGenres

    for (let i = 0; i < genres.genres.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[i].click = function () {
        getmovies("discover/movie?api_key=d80a54a0422d5fff6149c48741c8bece&language=en-us&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=" + genres.genres[i].id);
    };
};
}
```

The items themselves are created normally.[Genres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV4QP.png)The onClick function just doesn't work.

I tried to load this function as onload in body, but it didn't work

Comment: You only have one `dropdown-menu` div. See here `document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[i].click=`. What you want to do is add the clicks to the `dropdown-items` under `dropdown-menu`?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the clicks to the dropdown-items under dropdown-menu

Comment: It looks like you aren't closing your `<div class=dropdown-menu">`. You might be better off using `createElement` and `appendChild` instead of directly modifying the `innerHTML`

Comment: Can you do something like `let items = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");` and then do work on `items`?

Comment: The items themselves are created normally. The onClick function just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the API calls to focus on the code that was causing the issues:

```
async function getGenres() {
  const genres = {
    genres: [{ name: "pop" }, { name: "punk" }]
  };

  const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item dropdown");
  console.log("navbar", navbar);

  let nav = document.createElement("div");
  nav.className = "dropdown-menu";

  for (let i = 0; i < genres.genres.length; i++) {
    let a_tag = document.createElement("a");
    let link = document.createTextNode(genres.genres[i].name);
    a_tag.appendChild(link);
    a_tag.className = "dropdown-item";
    a_tag.href = "#";
    nav.appendChild(a_tag);
  }
  navbar[0].appendChild(nav);

  //This part should add separately to each element, but it does not work
  //Here is error: Cannot set property 'click' of undefined at getGenres

  const items = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");
  for (let i = 0; i < genres.genres.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("get movies here for name" + genres.genres[i].name);

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it, here is rough example. So just add event listener inside your `for` loop

```js
function generateLinks() {
  var container = document.getElementById("containter");
  var textNode;
  var node;
  
  [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(i) {
    node = document.createElement("li");
    node.setAttribute("id", i);
    textNode = document.createTextNode("Hello" + i);
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    
    node.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("hello " + i)
    });
  
    container.appendChild(node);
  });


}

generateLinks();
```

```html
<div id="containter">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @KiaiFighter. Here is the final code:

```
async function getGenres() {
        let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=d80a54a0422d5fff6149c48741c8bece&language=en-US";
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let genres = await response.json();

        const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item dropdown");

        let nav = document.createElement("div");
        nav.className = "dropdown-menu";

        for (let i = 0; i < genres.genres.length; i++) {
            let a_tag = document.createElement("a");
            let link = document.createTextNode(genres.genres[i].name);
            a_tag.appendChild(link);
            a_tag.className = "dropdown-item";
            a_tag.href = "#";
            nav.appendChild(a_tag);
        }
        navbar[0].appendChild(nav);
        console.log("nav", nav);

        const items = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");
        for (let i = 0; i < genres.genres.length; i++) {
            items[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                getMovies("discover/movie?api_key=d80a54a0422d5fff6149c48741c8bece&language=en-us&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=" + genres.genres[i].id);
            });
        }

        console.log("navbar", navbar);
    }
```